# What is the equivalent of a webpack loader when using the metro bundler in React Native?

Tags: react-native, webpack

When using the Haul bundler for React Native, I can add my own webpack loaders for specific file types etc. How can I do that when using the Metro bundler, which is the default for RN?

I looked at the docs but they seem to be a work in progress? (https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/en/configuration.html)