# Import yaml file in React Native results in number 1 instead of actual content

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

I'm trying to import a yaml file in React Native. I can see in the Metro `defaults.js` file that yaml is listed as an asset extension already.

The imported value is always the number `1` though and not the actual contents of the `yaml` file.

```js
import enYaml from '../i18n/locale/en.yaml';
```

[image: Debugger screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you're loading it as a resource.  So it's the resource ID.  What you'd need is an answer for [What is the equivalent of a webpack loader when using the metro bundler in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50931845/what-is-the-equivalent-of-a-webpack-loader-when-using-the-metro-bundler-in-react)

To do this in Expo which uses babel.config.js which Metro uses you need to add the `babel-plugin-content-transformer` as a dev dependency and configure it as follows

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      [
        'content-transformer',
        {
          transformers: [
            {
              file: /\.ya?ml$/,
              format: 'yaml',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
   ...
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, I've set it up exactly like this but my yaml is still getting loaded as a number. Any ideas?

Comment: To elaborate a bit, I'm using React Native + Expo and trying to import a yaml file. I'm using typescript, and I declared `declare module '*.yaml' {
    const data: string
    export default data
}` ( I know this solution loads yamls as objects, not strings, but I tried loading as a string as well and still got a number).

Comment: if you want to load the yaml file as a string then you use format: "string" rather than YAML

Comment: I tried that, neither "string" nor "yaml" seems to work, it always returns a number. It seems like the transformer isn't working at all. I made another question about this if you don't mind checking it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73920985/babel-plugin-content-transformer-is-not-working-on-a-react-native-expo-project

Comment: (it was a cache issue, all good now)