# babel-plugin-content-transformer is not working on a React Native Expo project

Tags: react-native, yaml, babeljs, metro-bundler, resource-loading

I'm using React Native with Expo, which uses Babel + Metro. If it matters, I'm using Typescript.

I'm trying to import YAML files as text (or potentially an object, but I'd actually like the raw YAML for some more complex parsing). However, when I import

`import data from "../data/myfile.yaml"`

Data is a small number, not a string.

[this person had the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64560601/import-yaml-file-in-react-native-results-in-number-1-instead-of-actual-content), and the answer states:

> To do this in Expo which uses babel.config.js which Metro uses you need to add the babel-plugin-content-transformer as a dev dependency and configure it as follows [...]

I've set it up, and it doesn't seem to be working, even though I've followed the answer and the documentation on the [content transformer plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-content-transformer). It seems to have no effect at all, `*.yaml`s are still loaded as a number/resource ID.

My `babel.config.js` looks like this:

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    // to support loading yamls
    // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64560601/import-yaml-file-in-react-native-results-in-number-1-instead-of-actual-content
    plugins: [
      ['content-transformer', {
        transformers: [{
          file: /\.ya?ml$/,
          format: 'string' // I've also tried format: 'yaml'
        }]
      }]
    ]
  };
};
```

Any suggestions? I'd really like to leverage this plugin, especially its feature of loading in entire directories as an array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now! All I had to do was clear the cache, with `expo start -c`. Previously, I had tried deleting my `.expo` folder and node modules, and it didn't work after that-- though it's possible I didn't do that correctly.

Anyhow, `expo start -c` for anyone having this issue in the future.